# QEMU/KVM: Creating file sharing between Linux host and MacOS guest

Tags: shared-folders, qemu, linux-kvm

I would like to create whatever possible way to enable file sharing between my Ubuntu 20.04 host and a MacOS Mojave running QEMU/KVM.

Things I've tried:

- anything related to virt-manager. Doesn't work because I run the guest solely via command line. Changes made in virt-manager have no effect at all on the VM
- the method outlined under "Manually": https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest by adding a USB device to the basic.sh file of my VM. Creates a bunch of errors I have no clue about:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `dac'
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: guest stopped busy async schedule
libusb: error [submit_control_transfer] submiturb failed error -1 errno=22
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
```

- I did transfer files via an online sharing website. That works but I want to take the guest completely off the internet so it really needs to be something that works locally between host and guest. A shared folder, a USB that can be recognized in MacOS... really just anything.

Answer (score 2):

On qemu command add

```
-virtfs local,path=<host_path_to_share>,mount_tag=hostshare,security_model=none,id=hostshare
```

On mac, open Terminal and mount it:

```
sudo mount_9p hostshare
```

The folder will be mounted in `/Volumes/hostshare`

Answer (score 0):

Run an FTP server on the host, if the guest can reach an online sharing website, a local one should do the trick.